# How do i move multiple svg rects on hover?

Tags: css, animation, svg, transition

> Basically 
>   i trying to make all the three part of the flag transition once the user hover at once not individually which what I've managed to do so far.
>   i tried using 'g' as selector but it didn't work

```
<style type="text/css">

.st0{fill:#ED9E4F;}
.st1{fill:#F1F7E7;}
.st2{fill:#83C553;}

.aller .all:hover {
transition: 2s;
height: 25%;
}

</style>


<g> 
<rect id="XMLID_12_" x="153.6" class="st0 all" width="7.2" 
height="12.5"/>
<rect id="XMLID_13_" x="146.4" class="st1 all" width="7.2" 
height="12.5"/>
<rect id="XMLID_10_" x="139.2" class="st2 all" width="7.2" 
height="12.5"/>

</g>

</svg>
```

> All the three part (rects) to slice downward at the same time no matter which one the user hover on run the code and you'll be able to get what im trying to say

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: read last part should clear things

Answer (score 1):

I would put the flag in a group and on hover I would transition the scale. I hope this is what you were asking.

```css
.st0 {
  fill: #ed9e4f;
}
.st1 {
  fill: #f1f7e7;
}
.st2 {
  fill: #83c553;
}

#flag {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transition: transform 2s;
}
#flag:hover {
  transform: scaleY(0.25);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="135 0 30 30">
<g id="flag"> 
<rect id="XMLID_12_" x="153.6" class="st0 all" width="7.2" 
height="12.5"/>
<rect id="XMLID_13_" x="146.4" class="st1 all" width="7.2" 
height="12.5"/>
<rect id="XMLID_10_" x="139.2" class="st2 all" width="7.2" 
height="12.5"/>
</g>

</svg>
```